# How to search a specific text into Two dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, django

I am new in python. I have a two dimensional list in django. Now I want to check if given text is in list or not. But its not working. Here is my code:

```
newmessage = 'Bye'

stockWords = [
    ['hello', 'hi', 'hey', 'greetings'],
    ['Bye', 'Goodbye']
]


for i in range(0, len(stockWords)):
    if newmessage.lower() in stockWords[i]: 
        return HttpResponse('Found')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Not Found')
```

The problem is it works only for first element of list, the second one is not working.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion?

Comment: This seems to be part of a function (that you have't provided all of). The first time the function hits a `return` statement, it exits - hence, when the value isn't matched in the first element of the list, it exits.

Comment: Also note that in Python you should never need to iterate over `range(len(something))`. *Always* iterate over the thing itself: `for i in stockWords`.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it, generate flatten one level lower list, and find in it

```
import itertools

stockWords = [
    ['hello', 'hi', 'hey', 'greetings'],
    ['Bye', 'Goodbye']
]

stock = itertools.chain.from_iterable(stockWords)
stock_lower = [x.lower() for x in stock]
newmessage = 'Bye'
if newmessage.lower() in stock_lower: 
    return HttpResponse('Found')
else:
    return HttpResponse('Not Found')
```

Comment: You are great man. Finally its working for me. You save my time.

Comment: One more thing. I am from PHP background. Recently realized that, I have to learn Python. But unfortunately I can't found out any good community for Python / django for question and answer. For example- like, Laravel / php, there is a good community called laracast, so, is there any other community for Python developer, except stack overflow?

Comment: i find the SO for my self, filter by tag `django`

Comment: Thanks @Bear Brown

What if I need to get iteration number in loop?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: your code checks for `.lower()` string, which isn't in any of the lists. ('bye' and 'Bye' are two different objects) I've tested my code without it, and it works:

```
>>> for i in stockWords:
    if newmessage in i:
        print 'found'


found
```

In order for this to work you need to lowercase all your strings in the list.
`stocksLower = [stock.lower() for in_list in stockWords for stock in in_list]`

Note it will create a single list, not list of lists.

---

You don't need to iterate over `range` when you have a sequence (list of lists in your case). You can iterate straight over it

```
for i in stockWords:
    if newmessage.lower() in i: 
        return HttpResponse('Found')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Not Found')
```

`i` now contains one element from `stockWords` list and test for containment.

Your original code was iterating over the `len` of `stockWords` which s 2. So it didn't check the inner lists.

---

Comment: This still won't work - if it's not in the first element, it'll exit the function.

Comment: Thanks. That's I did, unfortunately its not working for me. Its always check in first element of list, second element is not working here.

Comment: @tisuchi That's because you are checking for `.lower()` which isn't in any of the lists. I've tested the code and it works.

Comment: @Vinny, I used ```.lower()``` to make it lower case.

Comment: @tisuchi if you do `.lower()` on one side, make sure your lists are also in lowercase. I've added an example how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
newmessage = 'Bye'

stockWords = [
                ['hello', 'hi', 'hey', 'greetings'],
                ['Bye', 'Goodbye']
            ]


for i in range(0, len(stockWords)):
    if newmessage.lower() in [str(x).lower() for x in stockWords[i]]: 
        print( 'Found')
    else:
        print( 'Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stockWords is a nested list when you are using for loop its taking only 2 elements (2 list), you can flat the nested list or change looping logic so that you can traverse in nested loops too

Try this(without flat):

```
newmessage = 'Bye'

stockWords = [['hello', 'hi', 'hey', 'greetings'],['Bye', 'Goodbye']]

for r in stockWords:
    for c in r:
        if newmessage.lower() == c.lower():
            print("Found")
        else:
            print ('Not found')
```

If not mistaken @tisuchi is trying to create a function (wanted to return something) but not defining.
You can also use list comprehension. I have modified answer @WBM

Comment: Not sure what do you want from me, could you please rephrase your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
found = False
for i in stockWords:
    for j in i:
       if newmessage.lower() not in j:
           continue 
       else:
          found = True
          break
response = HttpResponse('Found') if found else HttpResponse('Not Found')
```